# PHP - Использование инстроспекция/отражение в реальных задачах

Tags: php, веб-программирование, ооп, рефлексия

В каких реальных задачах используется инстроспекция/отражение?

Кто подскажет, как и где их применяют в web-разработке? Можно с примерами.

Comment: Отраженние - это reflection?

Comment: Чтобы обойти инкапсулирование.

Comment: Alex78191, спасибо! Да, всё верно, однако, на практике ни разу такое пока не пригодилось.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, относится это к такому или нет, но вот, например, до php 5.6 не было возможности напрямую указать, что функция принимает неограниченное число параметров и поэтому для того чтобы имитировать это люди делали внутри функции func_get_args, а затем уже разбирались с параметрами.

Comment: Одному мне кадется это бредом?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, в чем именно? Пример я привел, как и просили. А на счет пользы этого этих терминов - я не спорю, они наверняка нужны в курсе программирования и далее используются для определения чего-то крутого и невообразимого. Но, наверное, действительно стоит убрать лишнее из ответа.

Comment: Александр, спасибо!<br> Смешно, но, спустя две недели изучения PHP и уже более сезона разработки я ещё их ни разу нигде не применил)))